# Can't pack blender file for rendering on a render farm

Tags: packed-data

Still really new to blender, I'm trying to upload a blender project to a render farm as my computer too slow, i am having trouble packing my "images as planes", i click on external data>pack all into .blend. When i try rendering online there are no videos as textures that i have on the planes as shown.

Also tried making all paths relative and absolute. All video files are on my desktop. The video files are 323MB, 516MB and 476MB.

So everything else is rendering fine but not the video screens on the "neon buildings" any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]
The result of the render with missing video files as textures for the planes.
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are your system specs?

Comment: AMD A6 processor, 1TB SSD, 16GB RAM, WIN 10 Pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Blender does not quite pack all external files. According to the manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html#packed-data):

> Not all external files can be packed
>
> Some typically heavy external files, like video ones from the Sequence
>   Editor or Movie Clips, cannot be packed in a blend-file.

I would look into the render farm that you are using. Some of them may have a workaround for this issue. Looking at those video sizes though, even just uploading 1+ GB of video would take quite a while.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I didn't now this, maybe i can make the movie clip smaller

Comment: I think Blender simply does not pack video files. If you're unable to find a workaround, I could help render on my PC. I'm running a GTX 1070, not top-of-the-line or anything, but it'll still render still much faster. Send me a message on Discord if it comes to that: stphnl329#4575.

Comment: That's super cool of you, thanks! I'll be in touch if I can't do it, i'm attempting zipping everything instead and uploading to a different render farm.

Answer (score 0):

Video textures or image sequences are not packed in the blend file. This is not related to the asset size, it's how Blender works.

I'm copying below the instructions for packing the files from RenderStreet. They explain how to upload projects both packed and unpacked, and also touch some other cases of assets that may need to be treated separately. I hope this helps get your project done.

https://support.render.st/portal/kb/articles/how-to-pack-your-blender-file-for-uploading

Also, I cannot speak about other farms, but in our case a project size of 1 GB is not an issue at all.

Disclaimer: I'm RenderStreet's CEO.